# Selecting multiple results from XQUERY query

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to select multiple columns from a query, but so far, I can only manage to select one. So I'm basically stuck with either selecting one, or all of them.

Here's my expression, what I got so far, which select only (1) column:

```
let $y := doc("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deaths_on_eight-thousanders")//table[preceding-sibling::h2//span[string() = "K2"]][1]
return $y/tr/td[2]/string()
```

I would love some explanation of how one would go about doing this, since there's almost no documentation of this lovely language.

Comment: @JWiley Maybe you can help me with this? Points points points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you like the result to be returned? You could construct new elements, or concatenate strings. There are many ways that this could be accomplished.

Here's one way to get comma-separated values:

```
return $y/tr/fn:string-join( (td[2] | td[4]), ", " )
```

You can [try it on zorb.io](http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/P2RgGVBJS35aTZ8W6Nbs6KEqpqw=).

**Update**

`(td[2] | td[4])` selects both elements, and passes them, as a sequence, to `fn:string-join()`. `|` is the XQuery `union` operator (and can be substituted for the keyword).

As far as documention, the [functx site](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) documents the standard library (all `fn`-prefixed functions), and has useful examples. And the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) are surprisingly readable.

Comment: Concatenated strings was what I was looking for. Golden expression. Thank you so much! :)